# Displaying foreign key in django admin panel

Tags: django

I cant seem to find the correct answer to display 1 foreign key value:
it displays "house label" in the correct "table" it displays the value. but it does not give the perfect "column" name. i would love to display "house_name" in the table.. any idea's?

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import UserProfile,House

# Register your models here.

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def house_label(self, obj):
        return obj.house.house_name
    list_display = ('user', 'api_key','house_label')


admin.site.register(UserProfile,UserProfileAdmin)
admin.site.register(House)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class House(models.Model):
    house_name = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=False, null = False)

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name ="profile")
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null = False)
    house =  models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "house")
```

Comment: Can you try to explain yourself more clearly? From the way you pose the question I dont really understand what's your intended goal. What does "perfect" mean for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want it to say `house` and display the name, you need a `__str__` method on your House model that looks like this:

```
class House(models.Model):
    house_name = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=False, null = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.house_name}"
```

and your admin class would be:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'api_key', 'house')
```

If you truly want it to say `house_name` you just need to rename your admin function and refer to it by that name in your `list_display`.

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def house_name(self, obj):
        return obj.house.house_name
    list_display = ('user', 'api_key','house_name')
```